# Update table after converting data from another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables, i want to update column of one table with column of another table where date is equal in both tables. Here problems is date in two tables is different.

```
SELECT UploadedDateTime = LEFT(CAST(UploadedDateTime AS DATETIME), 11),
        COUNT(DISTINCT ClientID) AS 'DocsCount' 
FROM ClientUploadedTaxDocuments
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), UploadedDateTime, 101)) > '1/1/2014' 
GROUP BY LEFT(CAST(UploadedDateTime AS DATETIME), 11)
ORDER BY LEFT(CAST(UploadedDateTime AS DATETIME), 11)
```

out put of above query is,

1..[image]

select * from FilesReceivedReport

2..[image]

here i want to update Y2014(Column of 2nd table) with DocsCount(Column of 1st table) where date is equal.

Thanks

Comment: Tried converting both dates to the same format?

Comment: Can you put the queries to create your tables and insert a few sample rows ?

Comment: @Raj - I think this question deserves a downvote. What do you say ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First, give the first selected column some nice name. Add "AS date", so it becomes

```
SELECT UploadedDateTime = LEFT(CAST(UploadedDateTime AS DATETIME), 11) AS 'Date',
    COUNT(DISTINCT ClientID) AS 'DocsCount' 
FROM ClientUploadedTaxDocuments
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), UploadedDateTime, 101)) > '1/1/2014' 
GROUP BY LEFT(CAST(UploadedDateTime AS DATETIME), 11)
ORDER BY LEFT(CAST(UploadedDateTime AS DATETIME), 11)
```

Then, try something like this:

```
UPDATE f set Y2014 = s.DocsCount FROM FilesReceivedReport AS f
INNER JOIN (your_complicated_select) AS s
ON f.D == s.Date
```